# Issue with JQuery Mobile External Page Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

I need some assistance understanding page navigation in JQuery Mobile. The documentation I've read assumes you are loading data into the DOM, which in this case I am not (not sure why, I took over this code base).

You can see below, I have a page that MVC delivers. When a user selects a link from the `ul`, it calls as function to set the `window.location`, rather than loading the page into the DOM.

My question is, is there a more correct way to do this for JQuery Mobile, due to this issue: in each function, `$.mobile.loading('show')` is called, then the window location is changed. This page is cached on the iPhone with the loading spinner showing, so if the user presses back, it loads this page from the cache, and the loading spinner is still showing. Since the it was loaded from cache, `pageinit` and `pageshow` both do NOT get fired.

So two questions

1. Is there a more correct way to show the loading animation from one page to another, that is not being loaded into the DOM.
2. If not, is there a work around?

Thanks

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<form id="myform" method="post" action="/Mobile/Device?isSearch=1" data-ajax="false" >
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li >   
        <h2 >  Search for a device </h2> 
        <p> <input type="search" placeholder="Enter a term to filter active devices" name="txtfilter" data-mini="true"  id="txtSearch"  />  </p>
        <input type="hidden" id="lbluserLatitude" name="lbluserLatitude"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="lbluserLongitude" name="lbluserLongitude"/>
    </li> 
    <li>
        <a id="lnkViolationDevice" onclick="gotoViolationDevices();">
            <h2>
                Error Devices
            </h2>
            <p>
                Only devices with Policy Violations
            </p>
            <span class="ui-li-count"><%= Model.UpdateTotalRecordCount%></span> 
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="lnkNearby">
        <a onclick="gotoNearbyDevices();">  
            <h2 > Active Devices</h2> 
            <p></p>
            <span class="ui-li-count"><%= Model.TotalRecordCount%></span>
        </a>
    </li> 
    <li >
        <a id="lnkInactiveDevice" onclick="gotoInactiveDevices();"> 
            <h2>Inactive Devices</h2> 
            <p>New or Decommissioned </p>
            <span class="ui-li-count"><%= Model.InactiveTotalRecordCount%></span>
        </a>
    </li> 
</ul>
<br />

<script type="text/javascript">

var userLatitude = "";
var userLongitude = "";

$(document).on("pageinit", function () {
    $('#txtSearch').attr('autocorrect', 'off');
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
    else {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
});

function showPosition(position) {
    broswerSupportGeo = true;
    userLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
    userLongitude = position.coords.longitude;
    $('#lbluserLatitude').val(userLatitude);
    $('#lbluserLongitude').val(userLongitude);
    //$('#lnkNearby').show();
}

function mobileLogout() {
    $.mobile.loading('show');

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Account/Mobile_LogOff",
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {

            window.location = '<%= Url.Action("LogOn", "Account", new{Area=""}) %>';
        }
    });
}

function GoFullPage() {
    window.location = "/Device/Index?mode=full";
}

function gotoNearbyDevices() {
    $.mobile.loading('show');
    var actionLink = '<%= Url.Action("Index", "Device", new {tabIndex = "2", latitude = "LatitudeValue", longitude = "LongitudeValue"} ) %>';
    actionLink = actionLink.replace("LatitudeValue", userLatitude);
    actionLink = actionLink.replace("LongitudeValue", userLongitude);
    window.location = actionLink;
}

function gotoViolationDevices() {
    $.mobile.loading('show');
    var actionLink = '<%= Url.Action("Index", "Device", new {tabIndex = "0", latitude = "LatitudeValue", longitude = "LongitudeValue"} ) %>';
    actionLink = actionLink.replace("LatitudeValue", userLatitude);
    actionLink = actionLink.replace("LongitudeValue", userLongitude);
    window.location = actionLink;
}

function gotoInactiveDevices() {
    $.mobile.loading('show');
    var actionLink = '<%= Url.Action("Index", "Device", new {tabIndex = "1", latitude = "LatitudeValue", longitude = "LongitudeValue"} ) %>';
    actionLink = actionLink.replace("LatitudeValue", userLatitude);
    actionLink = actionLink.replace("LongitudeValue", userLongitude);
    window.location = actionLink;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728410/jquery-mobile-login-link-goes-to-last-cached-page/13728853#13728853

Answer (score 1):

1. Is there a more correct way to show the loading animation from one page to another, that is not being loaded into the DOM?

   Short answer is not, it is not possible. AJAX loaded is called AJAX loader with reason, it will only work when jQuery Mobile handles page loading into the DOM. In this case page is never refreshed, thus it is possible to show loader during page transitions.

   In your case, each time you open new page browser will trigger complete page refresh, nothing visible can't persist during full page refresh/reload/open.
2. If not, is there a work around?

   Short answer is still now. As I already told you in your previous question nothing visible can't persist during full page refresh/reload/open. Thou there's one thing you can do. Because next page is still jQuery Mobile page you can show loader during pagecreate event and hide it during pageshow event, window load if your page is content/image heavy or during AJAX success callback in case you are using AJAX to load additional content.

   But again you can't have loader showing before you change page hoping it will still show after new page starts loading. It is simply not possible.

Is there a reason you are using? :

```
window.location = actionLink;
```

jQuery Mobile has its own method of handling full page transitions without AJAX, be it **data-rel="external"** attribute or **changePage()** function with **page reload** parameter.

### Update

1. Full non-AJAX change page through attribute:

   ```
   <a rel="external" href="index.html">Index</a>
   ```

   Read more about it **[here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html)**. Unfortunately I can't find it explained in current documentation.
2. Full non-AJAX change page through changePage() function

   First a warning, this function is deprecated but stick to it until jQuery Mobile 1.5 is out. There's a replacement function but it will not work for you unless you are using new pagecontainer widget. Plus pagecontainer widget is work in progress so it will be a bad decision to move.

   ```
   $.mobile.changePage( "confirm.html", {
       reloadPage : true
   });
   ```

   More information can be found [here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/).

Comment: I took over the code base, and the window.location = actionLink stood out as awkward, and now I'm here asking whats the "correct" way. I assume data-rel="external" is for standard links. Let me look into the changePage() and the page reload parameter.

Comment: I add you some more content so take a look.